# Permission Denied while installing

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7

I am getting the above error when i run the command:

```bsh
apt-get -f install
```

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

How can i overcome this?

Comment: With sudo at the beginning of your command.  :D

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Nobody runs that command without reason.

Answer (score 0):

In linux not all user can modify the system file.

Folder like `/etc` `/dev` `/bin` contains system's file that only the administrator is in charge to modify.

In order to install a new package, you have to use a root account.

Try with the following command:
`sudo apt get install -f`

`sudo` is a command that run the command passed as argument as super-user